# set value of input on form to a $_GET array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I have a page that is receiving an array from $_GET. Lets say it has 3 values in $_GET['types'] containing: 'good', 'bad', and 'ugly'. Now on this page I am setting up a form and I need to pass this array into the form through an input. Maybe this short piece of code can help demonstrate what I'm trying to do

```
<form action="dosomething.php" method="get">
    <input name="types[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['types']; ?>" />
</form>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, and...? What does it do, what doesn't it do?

Comment: you want 3 inputs? or all 3 values in that one input??

Comment: That is a very unsafe practice, use filter_input instead.

Comment: I'm making a page to query a database. The $_GET contains different filters for the query. The form I'm making is a search that loops back onto itself with the search query added to the filters. So I need to maintain the current filters already in the $_GET variable.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in string context are simply the literal word `Array`. You say `$_GET['types']` is an array, therefore you're generating this html:

```
<input ... value="Array">
```

You should have

```
<input name="types[]" value="<?php echo implode(',', $_GET['types']); ?>" />
```

instead.

But note that you'll end up with this html:

```
<input ... value="foo,bar,baz">
```

and this in $_GET on the server when the form's submitted:

```
$_GET['types'] = array(
     0 => 'foo,bar,baz'
);
```

If you want those values as SEPARATE array entries, you'll have to submit multiple input fields:

```
<input name="types[]" value="foo"> 
<input name="types[]" value="bar">
etc...
```

which will give you

```
$_GET['types'] = array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar'
    etc...
```